# Split String using regex or Unicode character?

Tags: java, regex, string, unicode

I'm practicing `String` split() method, I have this fragment of code:

```
String s = "Stack Over Flow";
    Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s")).forEach(System.out::println);
    Arrays.asList(s.split("\u0020")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

I'm wondering whether split using regex or Unicode char is better? Any performance difference here?

Comment: @Andreas: Helpful as always. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From javadoc of [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef):

> `\s` - A whitespace character: `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`

*Which is better?*
They are not the same, so whichever one that matches what you want is better.

Though `s.split(" ")` would be simpler than `s.split("\u0020")`. They actually compile to the exact same thing, while `s.split("\\u0020")` compile differently but generates the exact same regex.